# What does this code snippet to do with colours do?

Tags: java, colors

I was looking in to rendering spritesheets and this guy gave a tutorial where the spite sheet uses 4 colours: Black, Dark Grey, Light Grey and White.

These then correspond to a different colour through a method. E.g. black is green, white is red etc.

I wanted to use 5 colours instead of 4 but I wanted to understand this as well as it wasn't explained.

The Code:

```
public class Colours {
public static int get(int colour1, int colour2, int colour3, int colour4, int colour5)  {
    return (get(colour4) << 24) + (get(colour3) << 16) + (get(colour2) << 8) + (get(colour1));
}

private static int get(int colour)  {
    if(colour < 0)
        return 255;
    int r = colour / 100 % 10;
    int g = colour / 10 % 10;
    int b = colour % 10;
    return r * 36 + g * 6 + b;
}

static {
    Colours.get(555, 543, 542, 123);
}
}
```

So if someone could explain this and how I could add the fifth colour that would be awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it's taking a RGB scheme in base 10, and converting it to base 6

SO, if your color was the following

```
base 10 amount: 154
R G B
1 5 4
```

It would convert it to this

```
base 10 amount: 48
R G B
1 5 4 (in base 6)
```

Comment: Could you explain it a little more please?

Comment: @user2687097 to be perfectly honest, I don't know why they're doing it that way or what it's for.  they're just taking in `154` in base 10 and giving you a `154` in base 6

Comment: @user2687097 a base is the number of digits that your numeric system has, so the decimal number system has 10 digits `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9`, and is therefore referred to as base 10.